# Replacing a DLL while AppDomain is already loaded in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, iis, application-pool

What happens if a dll is already loaded by `w3wp.exe` and we replace it?

Of course we can replace a dll since asp.net uses a cached version of `Bin` folder DLLs, but I want to know if upon replacing a dll it will load the new one or it wait until next recycling or when there's no new request.

**EDIT:** DLL contains a singleton class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t990ks23.aspx):

> If you change the .dll and write a new
>   version of it to the `Bin` folder,
>   ASP.NET detects the update and uses
>   the new version of the .dll for new
>   page requests from then on.

Comment: My case is a bit complex. That's a `HttpHandler` and the DLL I replace contains a `Singleton` class. Since App domain is already loaded I guess new DLL won't be used until next `recycling`.

Comment: @Xaqron - it does not matter if dll contains `Singleton` class or not. It will recycle AppDomain and reload it.

Answer (score 4):

Your application will be compiled again once a dll is modified or added.

Your [application's domain will be recycled](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/08/02/asp-net-case-study-lost-session-variables-and-appdomain-recycles.aspx) when any change occurs in the bin directory or if its contents are modified.